# Why does BroadcastReceiver not get called?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

The BootReceiver never called even if the system was boot up using this command:

> adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -n com.android.canbedeleted.test/.BootReceiver

Permission I have put in the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.android.canbedeleted.test">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<application android:label="test">
<receiver android:name="test.Droid.BootReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>
```

The receiver tag i have tried removed it  but don't see any different.

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter (new string[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
public class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    { 
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("*********************************** Broadcast Received *********************************");
        Toast.MakeText(context, "Received intent!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        //Intent message = new Intent();
        //message.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        //message.SetClass(context, typeof(KeyboardService));
        //context.StartService(intent);
    }
}
```

Even if I tried to type the cmd like this, i will have stack trace as below. The test.Droid is the namespace of the class.

> adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -n com.android.canbedeleted.test/test.Droid.BootReceiver

StackTrace

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver test.Droid.BootReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "test.Droid.BootReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.canbedeleted.test-8.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.android.canbedeleted.test-8, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "test.Droid.BootReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.canbedeleted.test-8.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.android.canbedeleted.test-8, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>     at java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "test.Droid.BootReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.canbedeleted.test-8.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.android.canbedeleted.test-8, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>     at at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
>     at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>     at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>     at at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2513)
>     at at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:161)
>     at at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
>     at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>     at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>     at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
>     at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>     at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>     at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
>     at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
>     at at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver test.Droid.BootReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "test.Droid.BootReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.canbedeleted.test-8.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.android.canbedeleted.test-8, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>     at at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2518)
>     at at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:161)
>     at at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
>     at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>     at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>     at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
>     at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>     at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>     at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
>     at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
>     at at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>     at Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "test.Droid.BootReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.canbedeleted.test-8.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.android.canbedeleted.test-8, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>     at at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
>     at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>     at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>     at at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2513)
>     at ... 10 more

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713862/xamarin-form-android-doesnt-received-the-broadcast-after-reboot/39714163#39714163

Comment: I never force the application to close. I even have the activity showing on screen

Comment: Look at your *generated* manifest and the class names that is actually contains.

Comment: Now it works.. not sure is it because I haven't put the namespace on the manifest in the receiver tag. Now when I tapped in the command, the receiver receive the intent before and after the phone reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the receiver in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. You don't have to declare it there if you are using attributes like `BroadcastReceiver` and `IntentFilter`. Else the generated manifest (`\obj\Debug\android\AndroidManifest.xml`) will contain **two** declarations of the receiver and this might cause some issues. Using the attributes has the advantage, that you don't have to care about the correct class names.

Answer (score 0):

This `com.android.canbedeleted.test/test.Droid.BootReceiver` may not be correct.

> With the 5.0 release, the default package names for Android Callable Wrappers will be based on the MD5SUM of the assembly-qualified name of the type being exported. This allows the same fully-qualified name to be provided from two different assemblies and not get a packaging error.

Check what is the generated `BootReceiver` name, under your project's *\obj\Debug\android\AndroidManifest.xml* file.

Read more about Android Callable Wrapper Naming topic [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_5/xamarin.android_5.1/)